# How to get vertical spaces between inputfields in a gridsystem and how to change the size of an inputfield?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

Im currently working on some inputfields in React with Typescript, where all my inputfields are organized in a gridsystem which is nested in a cardcomponent and all the components are from MUI. The inputfields has this look at the moment:
[image: UI]

The inputfields only has horizontal spaces but i can't apply vertical spaces on them no matter what i have done. I don't know if it is because of how i have structured my gridsystem with the multiple containers or something else.
The other change i have is in the last column, where the inputfield for birthday is. The size of that inputfield is bigger than the other ones and i cant find any properties of it that changes the size of the field.

This is my JSX code for of the UI picture in the post:

```
<Card>
  <CardContent>
    <Grid container>
      <Grid container direction="row" spacing={6}>
        <Grid item>
          <FormControl>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">Name</InputLabel>
            <OutlinedInput id="component-outlined" label="Name" />
          </FormControl>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <FormControl>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">Last name</InputLabel>
            <OutlinedInput id="component-outlined" label="Last name" />
          </FormControl>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
            <DesktopDatePicker
              label="Birthdate"
              inputFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"
              value={value}
              onChange={handleChange}
              // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-bind
              renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} />}
            />
          </LocalizationProvider>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container direction="row" spacing={6}>
        <Grid item>
          <FormControl>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">Street</InputLabel>
            <OutlinedInput id="component-outlined" label="Street" />
          </FormControl>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <FormControl>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">
              Postal code
            </InputLabel>
            <OutlinedInput id="component-outlined" label="Postal code" />
          </FormControl>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <FormControl>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">City</InputLabel>
            <OutlinedInput id="component-outlined" label="City" />
          </FormControl>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container direction="row" spacing={6}>
        <Grid item>
          <FormControl>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">Country</InputLabel>
            <OutlinedInput id="component-outlined" label="Country" />
          </FormControl>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <FormControl>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">Gender</InputLabel>
            <OutlinedInput id="component-outlined" label="Gender" />
          </FormControl>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <FormControl>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">Email</InputLabel>
            <OutlinedInput id="component-outlined" label="Email" />
          </FormControl>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container direction="row" spacing={6}>
        <Grid item>
          <FormControl>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">
              Level of trust
            </InputLabel>
            <OutlinedInput id="component-outlined" label="Level of trust" />
          </FormControl>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <FormControl>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">
              Last signed in
            </InputLabel>
            <OutlinedInput id="component-outlined" label="Last signed in" />
          </FormControl>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </CardContent>
</Card>
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted answer if it is the right answer or if not provide feedback and help others to better understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give each grid item sx props and set whatever style you want. for example something like:

```
<Grid item sx={{mb:10}}>
    <FormControl>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">City</InputLabel>
        <OutlinedInput id="component-outlined" label="City" />
    </FormControl> 
 </Grid>
```

or you can wrap the content of grid item in a Box container and give it the desired style:

```
<Grid item>
    <Box sx={{margin:5}}>   
        <FormControl>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">City</InputLabel>
            <OutlinedInput id="component-outlined" label="City" />
        </FormControl> 
    </Box>
 </Grid>
```

and also for changing inputFields sizes you can use sx props like this:

```
<Grid item>
    <FormControl>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">City</InputLabel>
        <OutlinedInput id="component-outlined" label="City" sx={{width:"250px"}} />
    </FormControl> 
 </Grid>
```